# Read Json file and post to Kafka topic - What is the best approach?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a collection of json files and its content looks similar below sample. I need to read json files and post its content to a Kafka topic using Python script. Can someone help me out with a best approach? OR Reading a file line-by-line and post it to Kafka is the only possible approach?

file.json

`{"L1K1": "v1", "L1K2" : "v2", "L1K3" : "v3"}`

`{"L2K1": "v1", "L2K2" : "v2", "L2K3" : "v3"}`

`{"L3K1": "v1", "L3K2" : "v2", "L3K3" : "v3"}`

`{"L4K1": "v1", "L4K2" : "v2", "L4K3" : "v3"}`

Answer (score 1):

Use Kafka Connect. Ingesting data into Kafka is exactly what it's designed for, and it's part of Apache Kafka.

Two connectors that both support ingest of JSON:

- https://www.confluent.io/hub/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse
- https://www.confluent.io/hub/mmolimar/kafka-connect-fs

Comment: we don't have KC setup.(never used it before). would have to do it with Python KafkaProducer. also, for each line (message) it produce, we need to track the offset & other details in a DB. so that, on regular basis, anytime we can monitor how many message are produced and how many are failed, from which file the message was originated from, etc..

Comment: I mean, if you want to re-invent the wheel… ;) Kafka Connect does all these things (reliably tracking offsets, ingest progress, etc etc). To use it you run the worker (a binary that ships with Apache Kafka), install the relevant connector, and configure it using a JSON config file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need Python? `kafka-console-producer ... < file.json` would generate a new message for each line.

Otherwise, yes, something like this is what you want

```
import kafka

p = kafka.Producer(...)

with open('file.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        p.send('topic', value=line.strip())
p.flush()
```